# Regular expression for find in files in Textpad

Tags: regex, find-and-replace, string, textpad

I want to use regular expression for find in files in TextPad. I need to find URLs starting with "Areas/" and ending with "/pdf"(something like this Areas/../../...pdf). Please suggest me the correct regular expression for this. I have thousands of files and thousands of occurrences of these links.

Comment: http://www.helpdoc-online.com/textpad_4_help/html/findrep/findrep_usere.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> ^Areas/.+/pdf$

In 'Find' with "regular expression" checked off. You can choose "mark all", and Textpad will create a 'bookmark' for all the matches.

Please note that it will not match "Areas/pdf".

[image]